# Default Constructor in class file

Tags: java

If I don't provide any constructor, the compiler will create a default constructor for the class.

Will that default constructor is present in the class file?

If it is not present then how the VM run the class file and create object for the class?

Update 1:

I have created a class file,

```
public class ConstructorExp {   
    public static void main(String[] args){
    ConstructorExp e = new ConstructorExp();
   }
}
```

With the help of decompiler, I decompiled the class file,

```
/*
* Decompiled with CFR 0_114.
*/
public class ConstructorExp {
    public static void main(String[] arrstring) {
    ConstructorExp constructorExp = new ConstructorExp();
  }
}
```

As you see, there is no default constructor !

Comment: it is present in class file

Comment: Try it out, create a class with no constructor, compile it, then use an externam program, to decompile it.

Comment: @All: Please read my update

Comment: Use javap . Do not use any decompiler like JDUI etc.

Comment: @Gladiator9: Shall i use java decompiler? http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: @Lathy please use javap which is inbuilt disassembler of JDK. Do not use CFR  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html

Comment: try here http://www.showmycode.com/

Comment: showmycode.com and javap proves that the class file contain default constructor but it is not showed in java decompiler? any idea?

Comment: @Lathy - see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will that default constructor be present in the class file?

Yes it will.

You can check this for yourself by creating a class which has a default constructor, compiling it and then examining it with the `javap` utility ... that is included with your JDK.

Here's what happens when I do it.

```
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$ cat Test.java
public class Test {}
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$ javac Test.java 
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$ javap -c Test
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$
```

QED

---

> With the help of decompiler, I decompiled the class file [and there is no default constructor in the output]

Interesting.  However, that doesn't prove anything<sup>1</sup>.

What is actually happening is that the decompiler:

- sees the no-args constructor in the .class file with a body that is equivalent to `super();`
- sees there is no other constructor
- realizes that the constructor could be represented as a default constructor
- doesn't output any source code for the constructor ... **because** the code would be redundant.

<sup>1 - ... apart from the fact that the decompiler is a bit smart.</sup>

Comment: Can you understand it now?

Comment: Stephen: hmmmm Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is, this is one of those things java does, when it compiles a .java file to .class file. The same happens, if you don't put an "F" behind a float, or a "D" behind a double.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. Check for the answer below and compile a class a with no arg constructor. You will find the answer. Anyway explanation is given below

Default constructors
If you declare a class with no constructors, the compiler will automatically create a default constructor for the class. A default constructor takes no parameters (it's a no-arg constructor) and has an empty body. Because the compiler will automatically generate a default constructor if you don't declare any constructors explicitly, all classes are guaranteed to have at least one constructor. For example, if you declare a CoffeeCup class without declaring a constructor explicitly:

// In source packet in file init/ex6/CoffeeCup.java

```
class CoffeeCup {

    private int innerCoffee;

    public void add(int amount) {
        innerCoffee += amount;
    }
    //...
}
```

The compiler will generate the same class file as if you had explicitly declared a no-arg constructor with an empty body:

// In source packet in file init/ex7/CoffeeCup.java

```
class CoffeeCup {

    private int innerCoffee;
        public CoffeeCup() {
    }

    public void add(int amount) {
        innerCoffee += amount;
    }
    //...
}
```

The compiler gives default constructors the same access level as their class. In the example above, class CoffeeCup is public, so the default constructor is public. If CoffeeCup had been given package access, the default constructor would be given package access as well.

Link:https://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  The question is a very specific one - does the compiler write code for the default constructor to the ".class" file.